# How many Flurry projects can be created per Account?

Tags: java, android, integration, analytics, flurry

I want to integrate my app with Flurry Analytics service, but i would to ask whats the maximum number of projects can i create per account, and can i create the project programmatically via Flurry API.

Comment: pick the answer as correct answer, so that can be helpful for other also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of projects you can create with Flurry Analytics.  To your second question, you cannot programmatically create these projects.

Answer (score 1):

Bit strange that they have not mention directly in website, Even i have checked that [FAQ](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ) page but unable to find. but i think you can ask in [support page.](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: i asked the support but they gonna respond in 24 hours

Comment: Yeah,You have to wait because that is the policy.Might be possible that you can get before then that due to different timezone. Just make fingers crossed and wait. :)